# Sqlite FOREIGN KEY constraint failed during add column

Tags: sqlite

My issue is that I am getting a foreign key constraint error when I try to add a column to a table.  Not a row, a column!

My table is called Screens.  It has two tables with foreign key dependencies.  They are called Topic and ScreenTypes.  Both tables are very small and they only have 2 columns each (id and name).  The Screens table contains the columns TopicId and ScreenTypeId plus a couple of other columns.  All three table have primary indexes.  Everything has been working fine for the past few weeks.

Then, I tried to add a new column to the Screens table called ScreenNumber.  The new column is numeric and has no restrictions whatsoever.  But, when I tried to commit the change to the schema, I got a foreign key constraint error.

I thought I would get around it by removing the foreign key constraint, adding the column and then adding the foreign key constraint back.  But, when I tried to remove the foreign key constraint, I got another foreign key constraint error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I have no idea what is causing this and I am past my deadline for this project.

Comment: Does your new column have a default value or is it "not null"? Both of these can cause foreign key constraint errors.

Comment: The first time I tried to add the new column, I had a default value and not null.  Then, after I got the error, I tried adding the column without any restrictions at all and I still got the error.

Comment: Can you post your SQL table to insert the column so we can see what all could be going on?

Comment: I tried a few other things as well.  I think any changes I try to make to the table whatsoever results in the same error message.  For example, I tried removing the default value to an existing column and I got the same error.

Comment: If you post the SQL for recreating your table as well, we can try to figure what all is going on.

Comment: Sure.  I'm using SQLite Studio.  Here is the code it generates when I try to add the new column.

Comment: ALTER TABLE Screens RENAME TO sqlitestudio_temp_table;

Comment: CREATE TABLE Screens (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, Video TEXT NOT NULL, TopicId INTEGER NOT NULL, Instructions TEXT, ScreenTypeId INTEGER, SortOrder INTEGER DEFAULT (10), Image TEXT, ScreenNumber integer, NewColumn INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (TopicId) REFERENCES Topics (id), FOREIGN KEY (ScreenTypeId) REFERENCES ScreenTypes (id));

Comment: INSERT INTO Screens (id, Video, TopicId, Instructions, ScreenTypeId, SortOrder, Image, ScreenNumber) SELECT id, Video, TopicId, Instructions, ScreenTypeId, SortOrder, Image, ScreenNumber FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table;

ALTER TABLE Fields RENAME TO sqlitestudio_temp_table0;

Comment: CREATE TABLE Fields (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, ScreenId INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (1), Name TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT name, Label TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT value, AnswerTypeId INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (1), AnswerListId INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (1), AnswerText TEXT, PosCol INT DEFAULT (100), PosRow INT DEFAULT (100), ColSpan INT DEFAULT (1),

Comment: RowSpan INT DEFAULT (1), Columns INT DEFAULT (1), Rows INT DEFAULT (1), LayoutPattern INT DEFAULT (1), ControlTypeId INTEGER DEFAULT (1), Width INTEGER DEFAULT (100), Height INTEGER DEFAULT (21), FOREIGN KEY (ScreenId) REFERENCES Screens (id), FOREIGN KEY (AnswerTypeId) REFERENCES AnswerTypes (id), FOREIGN KEY (AnswerListId) REFERENCES AnswerList (id), FOREIGN KEY (LayoutPattern) REFERENCES LayoutPatterns (id));

Comment: INSERT INTO Fields (id, ScreenId, Name, Label, AnswerTypeId, AnswerListId, AnswerText, PosCol, PosRow, ColSpan, RowSpan, Columns, Rows, LayoutPattern, ControlTypeId, Width, Height) SELECT id, ScreenId, Name, Label, AnswerTypeId, AnswerListId, AnswerText, PosCol, PosRow, ColSpan, RowSpan, Columns, Rows, LayoutPattern, ControlTypeId, Width, Height FROM sqlitestudio_temp_table0;

DROP TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table0;

DROP TABLE sqlitestudio_temp_table;

Comment: Please add them to your Question, then delete the comments. It helps to keep all of that information together. Also, don't forget to use appropriate code formatting.

Comment: Sorry the code was so long.

Comment: Okay.  I have to go to a meeting.  Then, I will reformat my question.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Clarify via edits, not comments. PS This is going to be a faq. Google your error message without your particular names/strings/line#s. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My table is called Screens. It has two tables with foreign key
>   dependencies. They are called Topic and ScreenTypes. Both tables are
>   very small and they only have 2 columns each (id and name). The
>   Screens table contains the columns TopicId and ScreenTypeId plus a
>   couple of other columns. All three table have primary indexes.
>   Everything has been working fine for the past few weeks.

From the above and your comments then this appears to create the Screens Table, the Topics Table and the ScreenTypes table  and additionally populate the tables with some data:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Screens;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Screens (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, 
    Video TEXT NOT NULL, 
    TopicId INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    Instructions TEXT, 
    ScreenTypeId INTEGER, 
    SortOrder INTEGER DEFAULT (10), 
    Image TEXT, 
    NewColumn INTEGER, 
    FOREIGN KEY (TopicId) REFERENCES Topics (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY (ScreenTypeId) REFERENCES ScreenTypes (id)
    )
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Topics;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Topics (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ScreenTypes;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ScreenTypes (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

INSERT INTO Topics (name) VALUES ('Topic1'),('Topic2'),('Topic3'),('Topic4');
INSERT INTO ScreenTypes (name) VALUES ('SreenType1'),('ScreenType2'),('ScreenType3'),('ScreenType4');
INSERT INTO Screens (Video,TopicId,Instructions,ScreenTypeId,Image,NewColumn) VALUES
    ('Video1',2,'do this 001',3,'Image1','blah'),
    ('Video2',2,'do this 002',3,'Image2','blah'),
    ('Video3',1,'do this 002',1,'Image3','blah'),
    ('Video4',3,'do this 004',4,'Image4','blah'),
    ('Video5',4,'do this 005',1,'Image5','blah')
;
```

> Then, I tried to add a new column to the Screens table called
>   ScreenNumber. The new column is numeric and has no restrictions
>   whatsoever. But, when I tried to commit the change to the schema, I
>   got a foreign key constraint error.

The following works :-

```
ALTER TABLE Screens ADD COLUMN ScreenNumber INTEGER DEFAULT 100;
```

as per :-

> ```
>   ALTER TABLE Screens ADD COLUMN ScreenNumber INTEGER DEFAULT 100
>   OK
>   Time: 0.083s
> ```

and then using the following

```
SELECT * FROM Screens;
```

The result is :-

[image]

- As can be seen, there were no FK constraint conflicts and the column has been added and the default value of 100 applied.

I suspect that your issues with FK Constraints is that you are progressively try to correct issues.

First (at a guess) you try altering (renaming) the Screens table but can't because of the Fk constraint conflicts with the Fields table. You then try altering the Fields table but still you get FK conflicts, due to :-

> If an "ALTER TABLE ... RENAME TO" command is used to rename a table that is the parent table of one or more foreign key constraints, the definitions of the foreign key constraints are modified to refer to the parent table by its new name. The text of the child CREATE TABLE statement or statements stored in the sqlite_master table are modified to reflect the new parent table name.

[SQLite Foreign Key Support - 5. CREATE, ALTER and DROP TABLE commands](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

Of course, if acccording to your description, you only want to add the column then the `ALTER TABLE Screens ADD COLUMN ScreenNumber INTEGER` (with default value if wanted) works without the need to rename tables.

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the help.  I didn't realize that Sqlite had to build temp tables and copy data into them to add new columns.  And you were right.  I have another table called Fields that depended on Screen.  When I added the column to Screens, it renamed both Screens and Fields and attempted to copy both of them over.  The copy worked for Screens but Fields had some foreign key issues.

Comment: There were some rows in my Fields table that pointed to a non-existent ScreenId.  The FK constraint on those tables has been there from the beginning before I inserted the first row of data.

Comment: My database is being accessed by a C# application.  Is it possible that my application is somehow disabling the FKs?

Comment: @Mikutus By default, FK's are turned off, so you have to turn them on. See the link in the answer, section 2.